# Plot Pandas DataFrame and plot side by side

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

There are options to have plots side by side, likewise for pandas dataframes. Is there a way to plot a pandas dataframe and a plot side by side?

This is the code I have so far, but the dataframe is distorted.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import table

# sample data
d = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
     'jan': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
     'feb': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70],
     'march': [5, 43, 23, 23, 51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['total'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

# plot table
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
plt.axis('off')
tbl = table(ax1, df, loc='center')
tbl.auto_set_font_size(False)
tbl.set_fontsize(14)

# pie chart
ax2 = plt.subplot(122, aspect='equal')
df.plot(kind='pie', y = 'total', ax=ax2, autopct='%1.1f%%', 
 startangle=90, shadow=False, labels=df['name'], legend = False, fontsize=14)


plt.show()
```

[image: Side by Side]

Comment: How would you be satisfied if the current output results could be improved? Is it to match the pie chart and table in terms of vertical size?

Comment: A couple of things. Have the pandas DataFrame render as it usually does when displayed by itself, and align with the graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple to do with **plotly** and `make_subplots()`

- define a figure with appropriate `specs` argument
- `add_trace()` which is tabular data from your data frame
- `add_trace()` which is pie chart from your data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# sample data
d = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
     'jan': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
     'feb': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70],
     'march': [5, 43, 23, 23, 51]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['total'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)


fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type":"table"},{"type":"pie"}]])
fig = fig.add_trace(go.Table(cells={"values":df.T.values}, header={"values":df.columns}), row=1,col=1)
fig.add_trace(px.pie(df, names="name", values="total").data[0], row=1, col=2)
```

[image]